# Expand unix-style environment variables in C#

Tags: c#

Is there a way to expand unix-style environment variables (`$PATH`) in C#? The built-in function `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables` only expands Windows-style environment variables (`%PATH%`) and a Google does not give me any alternatives for unix systems.

Maybe someone has written such a thing?

I'm looking for something that could handle the following types of variables, so they can be defined in config files etc., the way you would expect on a unix system.

- `$PATH`
- `${PATH}`
- `~/` (should resolve to the user's home folder)

Comment: Unfortunately library recommendations are off-topic here... Which is really annoying, since I'd like to know the answer to this!

Comment: I'll rephrase the question without the library recommendation then

Comment: Funny, `ExpandEnvironmentVariables` has a unix-specific implementation in the runtime, but it mimics the Windows implementation: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/f59a132bfe9ff797f9d192d67f07673a13b6b29e/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Environment.UnixOrBrowser.cs#L23

Comment: @PMF yeah, there's an open issue in the runtime repo as well: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/25792